# Javasript inside JSX of react js does not working

Tags: reactjs, jsx

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

```
function App() {

  const [flag, setflag] = useState(0);

  const startCountdown = () => {
    setflag(1);    
   };


  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={startCountdown}>Start countdown</button>
      {(() => {
              if (flag===1){
                console.log("INN");
                      <h1>Count Down Started</>
              }
      })}
      
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Whenever the user clicks on the button, h1 tag which contains "Countdown Started" should be displayed on the screen.
But, its not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={startCountdown}>Start countdown</button>
      {flag === 1 && (
        <h1>Count Down Started</h1>
      )}
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a `conditional` to achieve this.

Sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-2qc1d?file=/src/index.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [flag, setflag] = useState(0);

  const startCountdown = () => {
    setflag(1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={startCountdown}>Start countdown</button>
      {flag === 1 && <h1>Count Down Started</h1>}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is never really run, it is just defined. Execute it using parentheses `()`. Also since you have curly braces you will have to use `return` keyword inside the arrow function.

```
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={startCountdown}>Start countdown</button>
      {(() => {
              if (flag===1){
                console.log("INN");
                     return <h1>Count Down Started</h1>
              }
      })()}
      
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with conditional rendering.

```
function App() {

  const [flag, setflag] = useState(0);

  const startCountdown = () => {
    setflag(1);    
   };


  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={startCountdown}>Start countdown</button>
      {flag === 1 && <h1>Count Down Started</>}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ flag === 1 ? <h1>Count Down Started</h1> : undefined}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and explain. E.g. Why use a ternary operator when `&&` will do?

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for information on providing quality answers.